# Ubuntu execute result from find command

Tags: ubuntu, find, pipe, execute

Im a bit rusty in Linux and I'm currently starting up again after almost 10 years. Im using packer+vagrant+virtualbox to do some provisioning and have run into a problem.

```
find . -name "someexecutable" | EXECUTE/RUN the file found
```

I need to pipe the result (always only one file) and then execute it.
How to do that?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the pipe you may want to do a command substitution as described here: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_04

Example:
   `find /bin -name "date"`

This finds the executable script "date" and executes it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If `someexecutable` is in `$PATH` then to run it, just type:

```
$ someexecutable
```

Otherwise, you could use `-exec` action:

```
$ find . -name someexecutable -exec {} \;
```

You could also pipe commands to a shell directly:

```
$ find . -name someexecutable | sh
```

To run several commands in parallel, you could use `xargs` utility:

```
$ find . -name someexecutable -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P8 sh -c
```